# Image and text will now not show up anymore on profile page after a change in code

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6

I was able to create a search bar, where you can filter the characters, for my directory.  However, when I click on that particular profile, the profile image and the text for it do not appear.  It was there before I created the searchbar, now it disappeared. Anyone know why that may be?

Prior to having this problem, this is how I had it set up. This is with the searchbar present, but not being able to filter out.

```
  {characters.map((data, index) => (
                <Button
                  text={data.name}
                  key={data.name}
                  title={`${data.name}`}
                  onPress={() => {
                    this.props.navigation.navigate("CharacterProfiles", {
                      item: data
                    });
                  }}
                />
              ))}
```

Then I made some changes to be able to filter out my options and I switched it to this:

```
{this.state.data.map((data, index) => (
            <Button
              text={data.name}
              key={data.name}
              title={`${data.name}`}
              onPress={() => {
                this.props.navigation.navigate("CharacterProfiles", {
                  item: data
                });
              }}
            />
          ))}
```

After the above happened, now the data such as the image and text will not appear dynamically anymore.  Anybody know why?

Answer (score 0):

In android some times image not load beacause of memory issue..

In Androidmanifest application tag set..

```
<application
        ...
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true" 
        ...
```